# Android BroadcastReceiver and starting an intent

Tags: android

```
public class SessionManager extends BroadcastReceiver{
Date timeOff;
Date timeOn;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if( "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.i("MobileViaNetReceiver", "Screen off - start time to end session");
        timeOff = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    } 

    if( "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        Log.i("MobileViaNetReceiver", "Shut down - log off user");
        DbAdapter_User db = new DbAdapter_User(context);
        db.open();
        db.handleLogout();
        db.close();
    } 

    if( "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON".equals(intent.getAction())) {

        timeOn = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        long diffInMs = timeOn.getTime()-timeOff.getTime();

        // convert it to Minutes
        long diffInMins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffInMs);

        if ((int) (diffInMins) > 15) {
            //log out user
            Log.i("MobileViaNetReceiver", "User inactive for 15 minutes - logout user");
            DbAdapter_User db = new DbAdapter_User(context);
            db.open(); // ******* HERE *************
            db.handleLogout();
            db.close();

        } else {
            Log.i("MobileViaNetReceiver", "User still active");
        }
    }   
}
```

When the screen is turned ON I am checking if the user has turned scrren off for more than 15 mins, if yes, logout him. And go to LonIn screen.
I want to start an intent when I call that handleLogout() (marked ******* HERE ********)
Can I do that when class extends BroadcastReceiver ? If no, what else can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You just use the context that was passed into your onRecieve function when you're creating your Intent. Once you have the Intent, make this call:

```
Context.startActivity(yourIntent);
```

Comment: I did ....Intent i = new Intent(context, LogIn.class); startActivity(i); It's saying create method startActivity(intent)

Comment: modified answer to address your question

Comment: What is upvote? How do I do that ? I marked this as an answer.

Comment: Yes, you've marked it as accepted which is good. You can also vote the response up (also indicating it was helpful) by clicking on the gray triangle above the 0 next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Blessings and happiness to the Google engineer who wrote the followint error message "E/AndroidRuntime( 2339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

```
public class AgeingAutoStartBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MyMainClass.class);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent1);
    );  
}
```

}

Thanks to everyone who writes helpful messages here

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can. Try

```
Intent yourIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(yourIntent);
```

If you want to do it in your `handleLogout` method, pass in the Context.

```
private method handleLogout(Context context) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a next step now. Thanks for replying.